# Solve $y'(t) = (t+y(t))^2$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve $$y'(t) = (t+y(t))^2$$ with $y(t_0) = y_0$ for all $(t_0,y_0)$. I'm not sure how to proceed with this because it is nonlinear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Substitute $u = y+t$, then we have
$$ y' = u' - 1 = u^2 $$

This is seperable